Angular: property isn't passed correctly
I have a component with a boolean property, with default value true
When I try to use it with the property explicitly set to false, it still gets a true value.
select.component.ts:
@Component({
  selector: 'my-select',
  standalone: true,
})
export class MySelect {
  @Input()
  sortOptionsByLabel: boolean = true
  someProcess(){
    console.log(this.sortOptionsByLabel)
  }
}

another.component.html:
<my-select [sortOptionsByLabel]="false" />

And I get true in the console!
Why? What am I doing wrong?

Please share the code that calls someProcess and from when in the component life cycle.

Thank you @BennyHalperin, this solved it!

Glad to hear that you found the solution

The problem was, someProcess was part of the setter of another input property.
So weather it saw the default value of sortOptionsByLabel or the value passed to my-select, depended on the order the properties were passed to my-select.
I solved it by moving someProcess to ngOnInit
Thank you @BennyHalperin for your comment!
